# Como passo um parâmetro para uma função externa de dentro do STYLED-COMPONENTS usando ReactJS com TypeScript?

Tags: react, typescript, styled-components

PS. A idéia aqui não é usar o parâmetro diretamente no styled:
`opacity: ${(props) => props.myArr[0].myOpacity)}` .
A idéia seria:

1. Passar um parâmetro (`myArray`) de um componente qualquer para um **styled-components**:

```
<Wrap myArr={myArr}> ... <Wrap/>
```

2. Receber esse parâmetro dentro de um styled:

```
export const Wrap = styled.div<{myArr: Object[]}>`
   //...
   ${ myFunc(props.myArr) } //<<< aqui minha dúvida
`;
```

3. Enviar esse parâmetro para uma função dentro do mesmo arquivo.

```
Function myFunc(myArr: Object[]) {
   //...
}
```

Comment: Não entendi ao certo sua necessidade... Você não quer escrever varias linhas de props no styled-component e então está procurando uma maneira de passar um "array" de estilização para que seja executado no styled-components no menor número possível de linhas?

Answer (score -1):

Vc faria assim...

```
import styled, { css } from 'styled-components';


function myFunc(arr: Object[]) {
  return css`
     // SUAS PROPS CSS
  `;
}

export const Wrap = styled.View<{ myArr: Object[] }>`
  ${({ myArr }) => myFunc(myArr)}
`;
```